# How to disable radio button control and enable text

Tags: swt

I have a radio control with text package. I need to disable the control for the radio button. But the text should be enabled.

Can any one help?

Comment: I see you're new to SO

If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 3):

The SWT radio button (`new Button( parent, SWT.RADIO )`) is a single control that can be enabled or disabled as a whole only.

Technically, you could use a separate radio button (without text) and a `Label` with a layout to position them side by side. Now you would be able to control their enablement separately.

However, radio buttons are a common and well-recognized UI elements that you would break by enabling/disabling the button and text differently.